# python for if one liner

Tags: python, one-liner

I have an issue.

I want to make my code simple and more comprehensible.

I'm trying to get the next date's value from data `x`.

Here is my code.
Is there a way to make it shorter using lambda or map?

```
def nextDay(date,x,time=1):
     res, c = None, 0

     while c<time:
          temp = iter(x)
          for key in temp:
               if key == date:
                    res = next(temp, None)
          date = res
          c+=1
     return res

x = {'2020-01-11': 3.4, '2020-01-13': 4.1, '2020-02-02': 4.1 }
print(x[nextDay('2020-01-11', x, time=1)])
```

Output:

```
4.1
```

Comment: can you kindly give an example of input and expected output data?

Comment: So when you search for example with `'2020-01-12'`, you want the code to crash?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going through the dates `time` times and always only advancing by one date, just search the given date and then read the next `time` dates.

```
def nextDay(date, x, time=1):
    it = iter(x)
    date in it
    for _ in range(time):
        date = next(it, None)
    return date
```

Or with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
def nextDay(date, x, time=1):
    it = iter(x)
    date in it
    return next(islice(it, time - 1, None), None)
```